# How to access cluster labels from a fit method in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, amazon-sagemaker

**Background information:**

AWS Sagemaker offers the possibility to use external Sklearn clustering methods, like DBSCAN, as well as internal clustering methods like kmeans for fitting and deploying/predicting. By default you have access to a clustered labels after deploying your method as a predictor object:

*Example:*

```
kmeans_customers_3 = KMeans(role=role,
                            instance_count=1,
                            instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                            output_path=output_path_cluster, # specified, above
                            k=3, 
                            epochs=20,
                            sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
    
kmeans_customers_3.fit(some_data)
        
kmeans_predict_3 = kmeans_customers_3.deploy(
            initial_instance_count=1,
            instance_type="ml.t2.medium"
)
        
cluster_info=kmeans_predict_3.predict(aws_conform_data_in_record_set)
        
cluster_labels = [cluster.label['closest_cluster'].float32_tensor.values[0] for cluster in cluster_info]
```

**Problem**:

When using an external clustering method from sklearn, these methods mostly have no `predict()` function. E.g. Agglomerative Clustering or DBSCAN have only a `fit()` or `fit_predict()` method, which is not compatible with AWS deploying, only methods that have a predict method, like Kmeans or affinity clustering, work well with AWS (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)

**Question**:

How can I access a fitted clutering model from AWS, so that I have access to `model.class_labels attributes` **after** **fit** (in hope of not only using clustering methods that have a predict method)? I now how to download the model.tar.gz but, I'm a bit confused what to do with it, since opening it does not help.

It could be also possible to write an own predict function for such a method, that only returns class labels, however, I dont know how to do that in this environment, since AWS uses an SKLEARN object, from which I dont believe I can overwrite or the method of e.g. DBSCAN itself.

Any ideas how to retrieve class labels of clustering methods from a.fit method in AWS Sagemaker?

Answer (score 0):

Once your Sklearn model is trained and saved in S3 as a model.tar.gz, you can download it to the client of your choice, untar it and re-open it with the same libraries you used to save it (pickle, joblib, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the way to open the `model.tar.gz` after training the model with [the built-in KMeans SageMaker algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/k-means.html), check the [Analyze US census data for population segmentation](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_applying_machine_learning/US-census_population_segmentation_PCA_Kmeans/sagemaker-countycensusclustering.html) SageMaker example, in particular, the section *Accessing the KMeans model attributes* that has this code sample:

```
Kmeans_model_params = mx.ndarray.load("model_algo-1")
```

The code sample, which you provided in your question, is correct, if you want to calculate (predict) the labels for all data points in your dataset.

In another [Bring Your Own Model (k-means)](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_functionality/kmeans_bring_your_own_model/kmeans_bring_your_own_model.html) example there's a code on how to pack your own KMeans model, e. g. trained with `sklearn.cluster.KMeans` for the inference inside SageMaker built-in KMeans container, in particular, this code is the main part:

```
centroids = mx.ndarray.array(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
mx.ndarray.save("model_algo-1", [centroids])
```

If you're looking for the way to host another SKLearn model in SageMaker, you need to create an `inference.py` script and define `predict_fn()` and `model_fn()` as in the [SageMaker scikit-learn Bring Your Own Model](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_functionality/scikit_learn_bring_your_own_model/scikit_learn_bring_your_own_model.html) example.